# how to search postgreSQL database column in Heroku console?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, heroku

In Herkoku Console

> ActsAsTaggableOn::Tag 
>   => ActsAsTaggableOn::Tag(id: integer, name: string, taggings_count: integer)

How do I search the name column for "foo" so that it will return only "foo"?

How do I search the name column for "foo" so that it will return "foo" and "foobar"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following works:

```
ActsAsTaggableOn::Tag.find_by(name: "foo")
```